# this is showing image inbox when i click on dropdown and it change when i change dropdown select

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script>
var g;
function pic()
{
document.getElementById("aj").src = "g";
switch (g)
{
case 'aj':
    alert("aj.jpg");
    break;
case 'aj1':
    alert("aj1.jpg");
    break;
case 'aj2':
    alert("aj2.jpg");
    break;
}
}
</script>
```

```html
<div style="float:left; width:280px;"> 
    <select class="input_select" onchange="pic('aj',this.value)">
        <option value="o">select</option>
        <option value="aj.jpg">aj</option>
        <option value="aj1.jpg">ajl</option>
        <option value="aj2.jpg">aj2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:280px; height:300px">
<img src="" width="300" height="300" id="aj">
</div>
```

how to do it.this is javascript switch case.and also image dropdown.this is showing image inbox when i click on dropdown and it change when i change dropdown select.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i will run the code and also show different image when i click on dropdown.

Comment: i not show image when click aj/aj1/aj2

Comment: can you solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got two version for you:**

**1. pure js:**

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/ggbrdws3/

JS

```
var selectedPic = document.getElementById('selected_pic');
selectedPic.onchange = function() {
  var picValue = selectedPic.options[selectedPic.selectedIndex].value; //selected value
  var aj = document.getElementById('aj'); //the image selected
  aj.src = picValue;
};
```

HTML

```
<div style="float:left; width:280px;">
  <select class="input_select" id="selected_pic">
    <option value="o">select</option>
    <option value="aj.jpg">aj</option>
    <option value="aj1.jpg">ajl</option>
    <option value="aj2.jpg">aj2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:280px; height:300px">
  <img src="" width="300" height="300" id="aj">
</div>
```

**2. use jQuery**

Try this if you don't mind use jQuery?:
(also try to not do inline script and inline style, move them to js and css style sheet)

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/epjb8pjj/2/

JS:

```
$( "#selected_pic" ).change(function() {
    var src = $("#selected_pic").val();
    $('#aj').attr("src", src);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div style="float:left; width:280px;">
  <select class="input_select" id="selected_pic">
    <option value="o">select</option>
    <option value="aj.jpg">aj</option>
    <option value="aj1.jpg">ajl</option>
    <option value="aj2.jpg">aj2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:280px; height:300px">
  <img src="" width="300" height="300" id="aj">
</div>
```

**3. LOL**

**ok if you really want to use switch use this:**

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/ed2jcj2L/1/

```
<div style="float:left; width:280px;">
  <select class="input_select" id="selected_pic" onchange="pic('aj',this.value)">
    <option value="o">select</option>
    <option value="aj.jpg">aj</option>
    <option value="aj1.jpg">ajl</option>
    <option value="aj2.jpg">aj2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:280px; height:300px">
  <img src="" width="300" height="300" id="aj">
</div>

<script>
  function pic(input, picValue) {
    var selPic = document.getElementById('selected_pic');
    var g = selPic.options[selPic.selectedIndex].text; //selected text
    var aj = document.getElementById(input);
    switch (g) {
      case 'aj':
        aj.src = picValue;
        break;
      case 'aj1':
        aj.src =  picValue;
        break;
      case 'aj2':
        aj.src = picValue;
        break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: it  can do use switch case in js

Comment: @ArunavaJana yes, then check my option 1, I just updated using pure js

Comment: @ArunavaJana you can use switch case but it is not dynamic when you update your select list you need to update the js code (switch case) too which is not idea

Comment: but i want to use switch case.please do it in switch case.